# how i pass multiple variables from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass 3 variables from view to controller. how I'll pass these using site_url,

**my view page**

```
foreach ($query2 as $row2) {
    $id = $row2->id;
    $month = $row->month;
    $year = $row->year;
}
<td><a href = "/money_c/updatemanual?var1=<?php echo $id;?>&var2=<?php echo $month;?>">insert</a></td>
```

**controller money_c**

```
function updatemanual($id, $month, $year) {

}
```

How will take this variables here `$id,$month,$year`?

Answer (score 2):

in controller

```
function abc($a,$b,$c){
// access the variables here

}
```

in view

```
<td><a href="<?= base_url("/money_c/updatemanual/$id/$month/$year") ?>">insert</a></td>
```

While calling the view in controller , pass the values like

```
$data['id'] = $id;
$data['month'] = $month;
$data['year'] = $year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like:

```
function updatemanual()
{

    $id = $this->input->get("var1");
    $month = $this->input->get("var2");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just modify it as bellow

```
<?php 
    foreach($query2 as $row2){
    $id=$row2->id;
    $month=$row->month;
    $year=$row->year;
?>
    <td><a href="/money_c/updatemanual/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $month;?>/<?php $year; ?> ">insert</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

this will be available as $id, $month and $year varialble for that controller function

Comment: showing error                 The requested URL /moneymanager_bank6_8_15/money_c/updatemanual/527/August/2015 was not found on this server.

Comment: you need to set your base url in congig and remove index.php and also mod_rewrite should be on and money_c should be controller name and updatemanual will be function name. if all this is  set then paste error message here.

Answer (score 0):

User below code. Hope it will help you.

```
foreach($query2 as $row2) {

  $id=$row2->id;
  $month=$row->month;
  $year=$row->year;
}
 <td><a href="<?=base_url()?>/money_c/updatemanual/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $month;?>/<?php echo $year;?>">insert</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<a href='".base_url()."money_c/updatemanual/$id/$month/$year'>insert </a>
```

then pass varibles through the controller function

like this way

```
   function updatemanual($id, $month, $year)
   {

   }
```

or you can use this inside the function

```
       $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
       $month=$this->uri->segment(4);
       $year=$this->uri->segment(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach and it worked for me:
`<a href="<?php echo site_url ('money_c/update_manual/'. $id.'/'.$month.'/'.$year)>insert </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href="<?php  echo base_url('test/index/'.$category_list[$i]['category_id'].'/'.str_replace(' ', '-',$category_list[$i]['category_name']));?>">

public function index($category_id = '',$category_name = '){
  echo $category_id .$category_name ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside foreach put the variables inside an array and pass the array to the controller like bellow

```
foreach ($query2 as $row2) {
    $var=array(
        'id'=>$row2->id,
        'month'=>$row2->month,
        'year'=>$row2->year
    );

}
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('money_c/updatemanual/'.$var); ?>">insert</a></td>
```